# ExpandableListView does not append the childs

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an ExpandableListView containing movie information. The groups are the movie titles, the childs are the media related to this movie (all included in the Movie object).
The ExpandableListView is showed but only with the groups, and when I click on them, the list does not expand. I debugged it and i figure out the getChildView is never executed.
I was searching but i cant realize why this method is not being executed.

```
ArrayList<MovieMock> movies;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.savedsyncs_content);

    ExpandableListView l = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpandableList_Content);

    laodMockedList();

    ContentExpandableListAdapter adapter = new ContentExpandableListAdapter(this, movies);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class ContentExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private ArrayList<MovieMock> movies;    
private Context context;

/*ExpandableList containing the movies from SavedSyncs. The groups are the movie's titles, the childs are 
 * the movie media and information.
 * */
public ContentExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MovieMock> movies){
    this.context = context;
    this.movies = movies;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public MovieMock getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("CHILD", "getChild : " + groupPosition);
    return movies.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return Long.parseLong(movies.get(arg0).getId());
    return arg1;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MovieMock child = (MovieMock)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Entro al hijo") ;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandablelistcontent_child, null);
    }

    TextView audiotxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.audio_text);
    audiotxt.setText(child.getAudio());

    /*TextView videotxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_text);
    videotxt.setText(child.getAudio());*/

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}

@Override
public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return movies.get(groupPosition).getTitle();
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return movies.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return Long.parseLong(movies.get(groupPosition).getId());
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String movieTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandablelistcontent_group, null);
    }

    TextView grouptxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ContentText);

    grouptxt.setText(movieTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

}
```

And here is the XML code:

The Group:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ContentText" 
    android:text="Content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/delete_button" 
    android:layout_width="20dip" 
    android:layout_height="20dip" 
    android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >
</ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The child:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layout_audio">
    <ImageView 
        android:background="@drawable/audio_icon" 
        android:layout_height="20dip" 
        android:layout_width="20dip" 
        android:id="@+id/audio_icon"
        >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/audio_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Audio"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/audio_icon"
    >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layout_video"
android:layout_below="@id/layout_audio">    
<ImageView 
    android:background="@drawable/video_icon" 
    android:layout_height="20dip" 
    android:layout_width="20dip" 
    android:id="@+id/video_icon">
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/video_text" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Trailer"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/video_icon"
>
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/layout_image"
android:layout_below="@id/layout_video">
<ImageView 
    android:background="@drawable/image_icon" 
    android:layout_height="20dip" 
    android:layout_width="20dip" 
    android:id="@+id/image_icon">
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/image_text" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Poster"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_icon"
>
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/layout_info"
android:layout_below="@id/layout_image">  
<ImageView 
    android:background="@drawable/info_icon" 
    android:layout_height="20dip" 
    android:layout_width="20dip" 
    android:id="@+id/info_icon">
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_text" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Movie Information"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info_icon"
>
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the records, the problem was the ImageButton in the group layout. I dont know why, but removing it i solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout my Example,

```
public class MainExpand extends ExpandableListActivity {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ExpandableListAdapter adapter;
    private List<String> parentList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<List<String>> childList =new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            parentList.add("parent "+i);
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                list.add("child "+j);
              }
            childList.add(list);
          }
        adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,parentList,childList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
     }

      public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

            Activity mActivity;
            List<String> parentList;
            List<List<String>> childList;
            LayoutInflater inflater;

            public MyExpandableListAdapter(Activity mActivity,List<String> parent,List<List<String>> child)
            {
                this.mActivity =  mActivity;
                this.parentList = parent;
                this.childList = child;
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
            }

            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
            }

            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
            }

            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return childList.get(groupPosition).size();
            }

            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                TextView txtview;
                if(convertView == null){

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
                    txtview = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
                    convertView.setTag(txtview);
                }
                else{
                    txtview = (TextView) convertView.getTag();
                }
                txtview.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

                return convertView;
            }

            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return parentList.get(groupPosition);
            }

            public int getGroupCount() {
                return parentList.size();
            }

            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                TextView txtview;
                if(convertView == null){

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
                    txtview = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
                    convertView.setTag(txtview);
                }
                else{
                    txtview = (TextView) convertView.getTag();
                }
                txtview.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
                return convertView;
            }

            public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
            }

            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but, if im not missing something, the difference with my code is that im using only one array for the parent and for the childs (because there is no reason to use 2). is that a problem? i understand it shouldnt.

Comment: thanks for answer, because m stuck on header click not able to expand childview but with the refrence of ur adapter i am done..